# Using django custom manager method as part of Q object chain

Tags: python, django

I have a custom manager with a method:

```
# managers.py
class MyModelQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    ###
    def close_matched(self, radius=5):
        return self.filter(
            matched=True,
            separation__lte=radius,
        )
```

Is there anyway to use the filtering in `close_matched` with a set of `Q` object filters, for use in a view?

As a simple example, something like:

```
q = Q(another_constraint=True) | MyModel.objects.close_matched(4)
```

but with a corrected object on the right side of the `|` (currently gives a `TypeError` since it is a queryset).

If not, I'm not sure what would be best practice here to avoid duplicating the code whereywhere, is it best to rewrite the filtering logic of `close_matched` as a `Q` object that I can call in `close_matched` and elsewhere in `views.py` etc.?

Comment: You can use `MyModel.objects.filter(another_constraint=True) | MyModel.objects.close_match(4)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right operand is a `QuerySet` here, and it is probably not a good idea to try to get the filter out of this, since that filter can depend on annotations, aggregates, etc. Perhaps not now, but later in the future.

You can however change the first operand to a `QuerySet` as well, like:

```
q = MyModel.objects.filter(another_constraint=True) | MyModel.objects.close_matched(4)
```

If you do not know what the model is of the right operand, you can fetch that with the `.model` attribute. For example:

```
some_q = Q(another_constraint=True)
q = MyModel.objects.close_matched(4)

q |= q.model._base_manager.filter(some_q)
```